# Why navigation is not in a same line with the other?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, nav

I was trying to make a navigation menu with a drop-down list but it becomes like this. I took the code for the drop-down list from w3school. Any help would be appreciated
[Here is my imperfect navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fw0h.png)

Comment: Can you link to code, post a snippet, jsfiddle, etc?

Comment: please post your code or a link to a codepen or JSFiddle

Comment: Can you post your code? Without a good example of your own code, nobody can see what is going wrong.

Comment: My codepen: https://codepen.io/peanut_butter/pen/xyKBQj

Comment: @Rice_Crisp https://codepen.io/peanut_butter/pen/xyKBQj

Comment: @CodeBoyCode https://codepen.io/peanut_butter/pen/xyKBQj

Comment: @Daan_1978 https://codepen.io/peanut_butter/pen/xyKBQj

Comment: Why didn't you do a ul li for the recipes dropdown part too if I may ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `padding: 14px 16px` on the  element within that `div` with the class `dropdown` - this is causing it to be pushed down

you would probably just want to use `padding-left: 20px` this should fix the issue

Comment: Thank you!! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: No worries at all! Glad I could help you! Keep it up!